# What is the name of this smoothing technique?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, noise

Let be $u$ a sequence that has too much noise

What's the name of the technique that smoothes out $u$ into $v$ by doing this? And what's the name typically given to the $s$ parameter?

$v_n = s \times v_{n-1} + (1-s) \times u_n$

$s \in [0,1]$

This is typically done in computer science for removing the noise from an incoming signal: as $s$ gets closer to 0, $v$ gets closer to $u$, but as $s$ gets closer to 1, $|v_{n+1}-v_n|$ gets on average smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) and the $s$ is the smoothing factor.